# Can I set a quota sub-limit per YouTube API Key?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have two different apps using a single YouTube API quota and each one is using its own key.

Is there a way to define that Key A may use X% of the quota and Key B may use Y%?

It is easy to see metrics by API key, but I have not been able to find a way to set a limit per key.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quota for the Google apis is based upon the project.  So when you create a new project in Google cloud console.  All clients wither they be web, installed, mobile clients as well as service accounts.  This includes api keys will all be under the same quota allowance.

If you want to be able to analytics requests you should know that the metrics shown in google cloud console are estimations they are not prefect.

There is no way to limit how many requests each key can make or even each client can make.